# kubernetes installation in windows 10 failed due to virtual machine set up

Tags: windows, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube, kubernetes-go-client

Hi I am new to kubernetes. I have read online tutorials to understand kubernetes and its benefits. To get hands on I have done a set up in my windows machine. It worked well half-way and received error while configuring kubernets VM.
I have downloaded Minikube installers and issued following command in windows 10 power shell

```
.\minikube.exe start --kubernetes-version="v1.6.0"
--vm-driver="virtualbox" --show-libmachine-logs --alsologtostderr
```

> Retrying.
>   E1104 23:10:01.364507   16152 start.go:122] Error starting host:  Error  creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm minikube --type headless failed:
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'minikube' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Kube\ .minikube\machines\minikube\minikube\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

I have oracle virtual box already installed in my machine.Not sure whether it causes this issue.

upon reading few other forums, i have deleted .minikube directory and reissued the same commands in windows power shell but it didnt help.

can anyone please guide me to install kubernetes in windows 10 machine.
I have no hyper-v in my machine(Windows home edition).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my oracle virtual box has network access issues. Hence it could not set up kubernetes vm. I found this issue when i start my "Docker quick start terminal", it shows same error as i posted above. Hence i uninstalled and then installed latest version of oracle virtual box. It resolved the issue. kubernetes cluster has been created in my windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the virtual box and installed docker toobox for windows from here

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#step-2-install-docker-toolbox

This will install Oracle VM virtual box too.

Open “Docker Quickstart Terminal”
This opens a Unix Bash.
Use this terminal for building docker images and running minikube.